# X1, X2, and X3 are distinct non-collinear points in a plane. Define an infinite sequence of......

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, intuition

X1, X2, and X3 are distinct non-collinear points in a plane. Define an infinite
sequence of points as follows: let Xn for n ≥ 4 be the reflection of Xn−3 over Xn−1.

Show that there exists a point A such that the triangles AXkXk+1, for all positive integers k, have the same area.

A question from CMI's prep book, understood it but was unable to get started w/ the proof, haven't made any progress, how do I do it?

Comment: A pity. It was a nice question, it had some air of originality about it.

Comment: @IvanNeretin should've framed it in a better way, have tried this but couldn't make any progress, have you solved it?

Comment: I was halfway through when it got closed. You know of Fibonacci, right?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, what's the relation though?

Comment: Say your points are just complex numbers on a plane. Then $X_4=2X_3-X_1$, and so on. That's a linear recurrence relation, and pretty much is known about them.